# Java: BigDecimal and Double.NaN

Tags: java, math, numbers, bigdecimal

I am trying to execute following code:

```
import java.math.*;

public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
            System.out.println(BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.NaN));
     }
}
```

And reasonably, I am getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException                                                    
    at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:470)                                                   
    at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:739)                                                   
    at java.math.BigDecimal.valueOf(BigDecimal.java:1069)                                                 
    at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:6)
```

Is there a way to represent *Double.NaN* in BigDecimal?

Answer (score 17):

> Is there a way to represent Double.NaN in BigDecimal?

No.  The `BigDecimal` class provides no representation for NaN, +∞ or -∞.

You could consider using `null` ... except that you need at least<sup>1</sup> three distinct values to represent NaN, +∞ or -∞, and that is not possible with `null`.

You could consider creating a subclass of `BigDecimal` that handles these "special" values.

You could consider implementing your "numbers" as a wrapper for `BigDecimal`, and treat `NaN` and the like as special cases; e.g.

```
public class MyNumber {
    private BigDecimal value;
    private boolean isNaN;
    ...

    private MyNumber(BigDecimal value, boolean isNaN) {
        this.value = value;
        this.isNaN = isNan;
    }

    public MyNumber multiply(MyNumber other) {
        if (this.isNaN || other.isNaN) {
            return new MyNumber(null, true);
        } else {
            return new MyNumber(this.value.multiply(other.value), false);
        }
    }

    // etcetera
}
```

(The above is illustrative only.  I would implement it differently.)

---

<sup>1 - The IEEE 754 specification also defines both positive and negative floating point zero values, and there are *multiple* NaN values.  These can be distinguished using the `Float.floatToRawIntBits` and `Double.doubleToRawLongBits` methods.</sup>

Answer (score 4):

> "NaN" stands for "not a number". "Nan" is produced if a floating point
>   operation has some input parameters that cause the operation to
>   produce some undefined result. For example, 0.0 divided by 0.0 is
>   arithmetically undefined. Taking the square root of a negative number
>   is also undefined.

`BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.NaN)` It trying to convert `Double.NaN` to `BigDecimal`, and result is number can not be converted in to `BigDecimal` i.e. `java.lang.NumberFormatException`.

Answer (score 3):

According to the docs it is not possible, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal%28double%29

Answer (score 2):

NaN = not a number. Its not a number, so it cant be converted to BigDecimal

Comment: BigDecimal is an object. Perhaps you only have it as null?

Comment: Reasonable suggestion.

Comment: "Reasonable suggestion" ... until you consider Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY and Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite your code like this:

```
 public static void main(String []args){
     Double d = ...;
     String value; 

     if (Double.isNaN(d) ==  true) {
         value= "My-NaN-formatting";
     } else {
         value=BigDecimal.valueOf(d);
     }

     System.out.println(value);
 }
```

Comment: If you use `BigDecimal.valueOf(d)`, you could just stick with doubles.