# java.lang.NumberFormatException with BigDecimal java

Tags: java, math, bigdecimal

I implemented this short code to calculate the (n)th Fibonacci number, but when it gets too big, my BigDecimal doesn't seem to work anymore. I get the following stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException
  at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:494)
    at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:383)
    at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:806)
    at java.math.BigDecimal.valueOf(BigDecimal.java:1274)
    at Fibonacci.next2(Fibonacci.java:42)
    at FibonacciPrint.main(FibonacciPrint.java:23)
```

Here is my code:

```
int index;

public Fibonacci(int index){
    this.index=index;
}

public  BigDecimal next2(){
    System.out.print(index + " ");

    return BigDecimal.valueOf(((Math.pow(1 + Math.sqrt(5), index)- 
                                Math.pow(1-Math.sqrt(5),index))
                                /(Math.pow(2,index)* Math.sqrt(5))));

}
```

and the print class:

```
Fibonacci f2 = new Fibonacci(Integer.parseInt(args[0]));

long startTime2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

line 23:

```
    System.out.println(f2.next2());
    long endTime2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Total execution time: " + (endTime2-startTime2) + "ms");
```

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: Please post the code in readable format.

Comment: FWIW, not an answer, but look around for "fast Fibonacci". There are better ways to get the exact nth Fibonacci number, using BigIntegers. "Fast doubling" is in my experience the best way to find it: https://www.nayuki.io/page/fast-fibonacci-algorithms. "Matrix exponentiation" is not bad either, but slower. I use fast doubling in my BigInteger implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BigDecimal` is unbounded, but the double value you initiate it:

```
((Math.pow(1 + Math.sqrt(5), index) -
                Math.pow(1 - Math.sqrt(5), index))
                / (Math.pow(2, index) * Math.sqrt(5)));
```

might be `NaN`, which cause this exception.

You can use `BigDecimal.pow` instead `Math.pow`.

Comment: is there a way i can fix this, like without using the BigDecimal.valueOf(double) ?

Comment: @Jlan Yes, replace `Math.pow` with `BigDecimal.pow`

Comment: thanks, didnt knew about the BigDecimal operations ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you extract the value that you used to initialize `BigDecimal` you can find that the value is `NaN` when `input` is large enough (say 500), like this:

```
class Fibonacci {
    int index;

    public Fibonacci(int index) {
        this.index = index;
    }

    public BigDecimal next2() {
        System.out.print(index + " ");

        double v = (Math.pow(1 + Math.sqrt(5), index) - Math.pow(1 - Math.sqrt(5), index)) / (Math.pow(2, index) * Math.sqrt(5));

        System.out.println(v); // <---- Here

        return BigDecimal.valueOf(v);
    }
}
```

To fix this, there are also 4 basic operations in `BigDecimal`: `plus`, `subtract`, `multiply`, `divide`, and even `pow`, so use the following code may fix this problem:

```
class Fibonacci {
    int index;

    public Fibonacci(int index) {
        this.index = index;
    }

    public BigDecimal next2() {
        System.out.print(index + " ");

        BigDecimal v = BigDecimal.valueOf(1 + Math.sqrt(5)).pow(index).subtract(BigDecimal.valueOf(1 - Math.sqrt(5)).pow(index)).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(2).pow(index).multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(Math.sqrt(5))), RoundingMode.CEILING);

        System.out.println(v);

        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: yea, now it also works with very big numbers as well. i had no idea of BigDecimal operations. somehow, it doesnt seem to be to accurate, as for example the f(99) fibonacci is 218922995834555169026, while the BigDecimal f(99) is 218922995834557172584, (...). when i implement this with bigInt, its accurate,  but it will take very long with big numbers while this implementation is working at a complexity of O(1). it cant be a mistake of the formula as it can be proven. maybe, i need to work on the implementation?

Comment: No, its complexity is not necessarily O(1), there is only one formula indeed but the computations in the formula here is not O(1) using `BigInteger`, if you look inside the implementation, it uses `char` array and do the `multiply` and `pow` operations by iterating array(s), but I have no time to dig more about the exact complexity now.

Answer (score 0):

Check what is the value of `args[0]` if it not an integer or is empty or is null  then the programme can cause `NumberFormatException`

**Update:**
When the number is big, > 500 it is probablly the NaN(Not a number) after computing, which `BigDecimal` doesn't support. Please see the following question to handle NaN.
[Java: BigDecimal and Double.NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28065158/java-bigdecimal-and-double-nan)

Comment: there is a number at args[0] but when that number gets too big, like >500 i get this exception

Comment: @Jlan: not every number, especially not something like Math.pow(2, 500) can be represented in a limited size floating point format like double. So you get a NaN or perhaps an Infinity. So if you start dividing, you are likely to get a NaN, and BigDecimal doesn't accept these. But look at my comment about fast doubling. Much more reliable, and gives proper BigInteger results.