# How to write NaN to biqquery in Java?

Tags: java, kotlin, google-bigquery, nan

In biqquery table, we can use `isNaN()` to check [NaN](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types) value.

But how to write NaN to bigquery table in java (JVM languages)?

Write string "NaN"?

Any comments are welcome. Thanks

### UPDATE:

we were trying to send `Double.NaN`, but the big query does not accept it and throwing exceptions. No idea why.

```
Error sending insert request, table: xxxx
com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryException.translateAndThrow(BigQueryException.java:100)
at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryImpl.insertAll(BigQueryImpl.java:979)
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:128)
    at com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:35)    
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonGenerator.serialize(JsonGenerator.java:134)
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonGenerator.serialize(JsonGenerator.java:173)
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonGenerator.serialize(JsonGenerator.java:173)
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonGenerator.serialize(JsonGenerator.java:173)
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonGenerator.serialize(JsonGenerator.java:146)
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonGenerator.serialize(JsonGenerator.java:173)
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonGenerator.serialize(JsonGenerator.java:105)
```

Comment: How do you usually pass values to bigquery? You pass primitive values and/or objects with the values. So pass a [`Double.NaN`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#NaN) value.

Comment: I'm currently fighting with the same problem. @BAE, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

`Float.NaN` or `Double.NaN` will not work.

Under the hood the Java BigQuery API uses the [Google HTTP Client Library for Java](https://github.com/googleapis/google-http-java-client).

Neither `NaN` nor infinity are supported JSON symbols. Probably for that reason, when serializing the provided data, [`JsonGenerator`](https://github.com/googleapis/google-http-java-client/blob/main/google-http-client/src/main/java/com/google/api/client/json/JsonGenerator.java) [explicitly forbids it](https://github.com/googleapis/google-http-java-client/blob/ea0f6c0f58e8abffae1362feb344a9309d6d814e/google-http-client/src/main/java/com/google/api/client/json/JsonGenerator.java#L133-L135):

```java
double doubleValue = ((Number) value).doubleValue();
Preconditions.checkArgument(!Double.isInfinite(doubleValue) && !Double.isNaN(doubleValue));
writeNumber(doubleValue);
```

*As a side note, in contrast, the library allows parsing this values. Please, see the [relevant commit](https://github.com/googleapis/google-http-java-client/commit/926e04d07b8aee3b849922f67cea462eadc656b0).*

In addition two the aforementioned cases, in Java you cannot provide the `NaN` value by [other mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28065158/java-bigdecimal-and-double-nan/28065194).

In my opinion, `NaN` is not conceived to be passed as a function argument, rather they should be considered a computational error or the result of some kind of overflow like the one that could be caused in `IEEE_DIVIDE`, and that is the [reason for the existence](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#floating_point_semantics) of the data type in BigQuery:

> Function calls and operators return an overflow error if the input is
> finite but the output would be non-finite. If the input contains non-finite
> values, the output can be non-finite. In general functions do not introduce
> `NaN`s or `+/-inf`. However, specific functions like `IEEE_DIVIDE` can
> return non-finite values on finite input. All such cases are noted
> explicitly in Mathematical functions.

Instead of using `NaN`, please treat then as `null` values: that is the approach followed in other languages.

Comment: BAE, @TobiasHermann, I posted a n answer try explaining why I think it is not possible, and why I think it is preferable to use `null` values instead. Please, could you indicate why `NaN` is necessary? Which is the actual use case?

Comment: Thanks a lot! My use-case is, that I have Avro-serialized domain events on Kafka (event sourcing), and want to have them all in BigQuery. Some of these domain events happen to have arrays of (non-nullable) floats, some of which are `NaN`. Of course, it would be nicer if there were no `NaN`s, but now the events are there, and since Avro allows that, my service, that is streaming events into BigQuery, must be ready to handle these cases.

Comment: You are welcome @TobiasHermann. Thank you very much for the feedback. That is an interesting problem indeed. Please, could you further describe the actual mechanism that is writing the information to BigQuery? I mean, are you using some kind of connector provided by Confluent, for instance? Did you build a custom Kafka consumer?

Comment: Initially, I tried using Kafka Connect, but ran into too many problems, e.g., deriving table names, etc.. Then I tried Apache Beam, but also ran into issues, e.g., some timestamps in our events being `timestamp-millis` and some `timestamp-micros`. Now, I'm using a custom Kafka consumer (Spring Boot) and stream the events into BigQuery using the Java API, which works nicely (so far), and gives me a lot of freedom, e.g., deriving BQ table TTLs from Kafka topics retention settings, deriving a `date` column for partitioning from a TS field in a common struct in our events, etc.

Comment: That is great @TobiasHermann, it looks like a very good solution.

Comment: NaN is routine in data science applications and supported well by Python, R, etc. Indeed it is supported by BigQuery. So it's frustrating that, whenever JSON shows up, then the parsers all start to break. Has anyone [yet] written a UDF for BigQuery that provides the functionality of JSON_EXTRACT but which allows NaN ?

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and gives you few ways of generating Nan, I just wrapped it with IS_NaN to check that result is actually NaN and not just string 'NaN'

```
SELECT
  test1,
  IS_NAN(test1),
  test2,
  IS_NAN(test2)
FROM (  
SELECT 
  IEEE_DIVIDE(0, 0) test1, 
  CAST('NaN' AS FLOAT64) test2
)
```

with result

```
Row test1   f0_     test2   f1_  
1   NaN     true    NaN     true
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you also know a solution on how to insert NaNs using the Java API? I run into [the same `IllegalArgumentException` problem](https://gist.github.com/Dobiasd/68d664405098d5b15acbe04b39b768ad) as op.